# Excel truncates csv lines after encountering commas even when a different delimiter is selected

Tags: ms-office

I have a csv file in which the delimiter is `~` . In the `Text to Data` dialog the delimiter is chosen appropriately:

[image]

Here is one row for size:

```
 NCT00392171~outcome~1934277~O1~Outcome~temozolomide~NCT00392171~The Effects of Continuous 28-day (28/28) Temozolomide Chemotherapy in Subjects With Recurrent Malignant Glioma Who Have Failed the Conventional 5-day (5/28) Treatment (P04601)~Completed~Phase 2~Temozolomide~120~Interventional~results_reference~astrocytoma,glioblastoma,glioma,oligodendroglioma~20308655~4398002~Percentage of Participants Surviving at Six Months of Treatment Without Evidence of Disease Progression.~Rechallenge Glioblastoma Multiforme (GBM) (n=28)~""~Percentage of Participants~Number~35.7~~~~1383586~Participants~116~Measure~581541~Primary~Percentage of Participants Surviving at Six Months of Treatment Without Evidence of Disease Progression.~6 months~Participants who rec~Percentage of Participants~""~""~Number~1
```

The column of particular interest is "O" that happens to contain commas in it: an example entry is:

```
astrocytoma,glioblastoma,glioma,oligodendroglioma
```

when `Text to Columns` feature was invoked all of the columns to the right of O are empty - even though the original csv has entries for all of them.

[image]

It thus appears there were  a serious problem in excel handling of imports using a non-comma delimiter.  For those of you that have noticed this: do  have you found a workaround?

Comment: Which version of Excel? Would you be able to make a short sample of the CSV which triggers the issue available for download in case somebody wants to try themselves?

Comment: Have you tried opening the _file_ in other _spreadsheet_ apps like **Numbers** or **LibreOffice** and had the same results? Have you tried changing the _delimiter_ via e.g. `sed` or `tr` to _tab_ and did that make any difference?